# Yii - Submitting a form to different controller

Tags: php, yii

I have created a form using Gii and copied the form and all the fields to a different page. To be specific, embedding this form into the homepage.

```
$form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
                            'id'=>'get-in-touch-form',
```

Now when I submit the form it doesn't do anything because it calling begingWidget with $this object

```
$this->beginWidget(
```

when I do `echo get_class($this)` it showing me `SiteController` which makes sense since I am embedding the code in the homepage. 
In this case I want to call the `beginWidget`method inside `GetInTouchController` 
How can I call make this method call?
I have tried

```
$getInTouch = new GetInTouchController();
$form=$getInTouch->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
```

and

```
$form=GetInTouchController::beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
```

but in both cases, it shows the error

```
include(GetInTouchController.php): failed to open stream
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want call a different controller action in yii1 you should set action

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'form-id',
    'action' => Yii::app()->createUrl('GetInTouch/yourAction '), //<- your form action here

)); ?>
```